# A set of inequalities

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $\{a_{1},\cdots,a_{n}\}$ be a set of non-negative numbers, and let 
 $\{c_{1},\cdots,c_{n}\}$ be a set of positive numbers, proof or give a counterexample for the follow affirmation:
 $$\min_{n}\{c_{n}\}\max\{a_{n}\}\ge \max_{n}\{a_{n}c_{n}\}$$

Please someone can help me with this question? If it is true, is it true for $n$ infinite too?

Comment: It is not true.  Try to think of an example where $n=2$ and $c_n$ has two different values.  If you're still stuck after trying a few examples, I'll give an additional hint.

Comment: sure, just take $a_{n}>0$ and constant, and as you said $c_{n}$ with distinct values. Thank you!